# TFS (Git) notifications for commits

Tags: tfs

I want to setup notifications for commits happened by anyone. It seems I have to add people one by one. Is there a better solution ?

How to do that ?

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.122.27102.1